# vscode, проблема с терминалом

Tags: консоль, visual-studio-code, assets

У меня в vscode после переустановки приложения, при открытии терминала не хватает каких-то assets, из-за этого показываются квадратики. Может кто-то сталкивался и знает как решить эту проблему?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шрифт плохой - без поддержки треугольничков из юникода.

Посмотрите какой шрифт стоит в нормальном терминале, и поставьте тот же в терминале VSC.